# Cannot install Apache Web Server on Ubuntu, Amazon WS

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I enter command `apt-get install apache2 --fix-missing` (under the root user) and this is what I receive:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-worker apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap
  ssl-cert
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec apache2-suexec-custom openssl-blacklist
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-worker apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap ssl-cert
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,945 kB/3,141 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main apache2.2-bin i386 2.2.20-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 10.161.51.124 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/main apache2.2-bin i386 2.2.20-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/main apache2-utils i386 2.2.20-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/main apache2.2-common i386 2.2.20-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/main apache2-mpm-worker i386 2.2.20-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/main apache2 i386 2.2.20-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2.2-bin_2.2.20-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-utils_2.2.20-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2.2-common_2.2.20-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-mpm-worker_2.2.20-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.2.20-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Aborting install.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try running the following command beforehand:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Depending on your installation, you might also want to run

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to install package updates.